Word VBA: Input text at top of page
I am working on a VBA project to automate writing a common report. The report requires 'headers' at the top of each page with page number and some identifying information. The kicker is this 'header' can't actually be in Word's header space, it must be within the regular text body. The header is applicable for all but the first and last page.
I've written the following code to do this. The block below is the last thing executed before saving the file. The issue I am having is that the text typed is only at the top of the page for the first iteration of the loop. Subsequent iterations are on the correct page but 2-3 lines down from the top.
p = 2
pTot = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count

Do While p < pTot
   Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=p
   Selection.TypeText Text:= "header text page " & CStr(p-1)
   ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
   p = p + 1
Loop

It behaves as though the top of each page was decided before entering the Do Loop rather than reassessing each time through the loop. I tried to force a reassessment with ActiveDocument.Fields.Update but that is unsuccessful.
How can I make sure the selection is at the top of a given page before typing text?

Use the range object instead of selection and InsertBefore:
Sub insertHeader()

Dim pTot As Long, rg As Range
With ActiveDocument
    pTot = .ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count
    Set rg = .Content
End With

Dim p As Long
For p = 2 To pTot - 1
   Set rg = rg.GoTo(what:=wdGoToPage, Count:=p)
   rg.InsertBefore "header text page " & CStr(p - 1)
Next

With ActiveDocument
    .Fields.Update
End With

End Sub


Here, I have to force repagination, e.g. by inserting a Repaginate before your Loop statement:
p = 2
pTot = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count

Do While p < pTot
   Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=p
   Selection.TypeText Text:= "header text page " & CStr(p-1)
   ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
   p = p + 1
   ActiveDocument.Repaginate
Loop

I believe the problem is that Word always repaginates in the background (not sure you can even turn that off these days, despite the Options.Pagination setting). Although it constantly revisits and updates fields in the header/footer, that in itself is not enough to guarantee that re-pagination will occur before the next .TypeText is executed. Even DoEvents did not work here, although it did change behaviour slightly in one of my tests).
